# Difference between ./script and sh script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

What's the difference between:

```
 sh myscript.sh
```

and

```
./myscript.sh
```

Comment: Type `readlink -f $(type -p sh)` in the shell, I guess this is not really sh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#!/bin/sh` loads `sh` from that path.  If on Linux then it is likely a symbolic link to `bash`.

`sh tremor_script.sh` uses the `PATH` environment variable to find `sh`, which might be totally different.

Track down which `sh` you are using, maybe using `which sh`, and following any links.
Note that Android uses `ash` or `mksh`, depending on the Android version.

However, messages like "junk at end of line" might come from files that have been copied from Windows without the \r\n line endings corrected to \n.

Comment: nailed it.  The `#!/bin/sh` is called a `shebang`.  It's short for `Crash(#)-Bang(!)`.  This line tells the system to use whatever file you specify afterwards to be used to execute the file.  In this case, `/bin/sh`.  When you type `sh tremor_script.sh` the system uses whichever `sh` program is in your current `$PATH`.  Find out what's screwed up there and you'll be set.

Comment: Yes ok, I think I got the difference. But on my computer, sh command is pointing to /bin/sh too, so it's weird. I don't know where I should look for this odd behaviour...

Comment: OK, what if you type `/bin/sh tremor_script.sh` ?  Second: try `/bin/sh -x tremor_script.sh`.  The -x should give you a trace which might give some clues. Finally, what the heck is `floor1ARM.s`?

Comment: well, the -x shows me the same thing by running the script into the terminal or inside another script. I'll keep searching; and floor1ARM.s is one file of the tremor library.